# Intellij 12 and internal compilation error when building scala project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have just downloaded Intellij 12.01 (build #IC-123.94) and once I try to build a Scala project I get the following stacktrace:

```
Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BinaryContent
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BinaryContent
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.LazyCompiledClass.<init>(ScalaBuilder.scala:239)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.IdeClient.generated(ScalaBuilder.scala:230)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ClientEventProcessor.process(ClientEventProcessor.scala:17)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer$.liftedTree1$1(RemoteServer.scala:76)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer$.org$jetbrains$jps$incremental$scala$remote$RemoteServer$$handle(RemoteServer.scala:74)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteServer.scala:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteServer.scala:43)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:15)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteServer.scala:43)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteServer.scala:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:15)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteServer.scala:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteServer.scala:39)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.package$.using(package.scala:15)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.send(RemoteServer.scala:39)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.compile(RemoteServer.scala:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:110)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:100)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:536)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:100)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:99)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:99)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder$$anonfun$5.apply(ScalaBuilder.scala:98)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder.doBuild(ScalaBuilder.scala:98)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder.build(ScalaBuilder.scala:67)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderService$ScalaBuilderDecorator.build(ScalaBuilderService.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:963)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:710)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:740)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:673)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:494)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:274)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:164)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:114)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:205)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:102)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Apparently, the problem comes from the openapi.jar inside the Intellij's lib folder, which was supposed to contain such a class.

Any pointers?

Regards.

Comment: If problem is definitely from openapi why don't you use jetbrains bugtracker?

Comment: Your installation may be corrupted, try to reinstall into an empty directory. The class file reported as not found is located at `IDEA\lib\jps-server.jar\org\jetbrains\jps\javac\BinaryContent.class`

Comment: Did you install the Scala plugin for the new version?

Comment: Hi Luigi, yes I did. I installed it from the Idea itself.

Comment: Hi CrazyCoder... it is not corrupted. I know the problem is related to the openapi jar. It exists inside lib, but the BinaryContent class is not there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same issue with Idea 12, but after updating the Scala plugin to version 0.7.62, problem has been solved for me.

However, you can try to follow Idea's advice:

> In case of any compilation problems you may enable the previous (internal) compiler by clearing:
>            Project Settings / Compiler / Use external build

Comment: Had the same issue, tried a lot of suggested solutions, didn't fix. I cleared the "use external build" and that worked. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me too, fixed by updating to nightly builds (0.7.82), instructions available here: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/SCA/Scala+Plugin+Nightly+Builds+for+Leda