# Scala 2.8 HelloWorld Program ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala

I'm trying to run a scala program,

```
class HelloWorld {
  var myField = 0;

  def getMyField() : Int = {
    return this.myField;
  }

}
```

I keep getting a `ClassNotFoundException` even though the program is named `HelloWorld.scala`

Full Error below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:122)
```

Okay, looking at the documentation of scala http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html

I changed the code to this,

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

This is the error now

```
Information:24/7/15 10:55 AM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 7 warnings in 2s 32ms
Error:scalac: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.ServerException
Error compiling sbt component 'compiler-interface-2.8.0.final-51.0'
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:145)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
    at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:285)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:142)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$$anonfun$compileSources$1.apply(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
    at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:285)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler$.compileSources(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:139)
    at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInterfaceJar(IncrementalCompiler.scala:33)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$.org$jetbrains$jps$incremental$scala$local$CompilerFactoryImpl$$getOrCompileInterfaceJar(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:87)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl$$anonfun$getScalac$1.apply(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.getScalac(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:43)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CompilerFactoryImpl.createCompiler(CompilerFactoryImpl.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory$$anonfun$createCompiler$1.apply(CachingFactory.scala:24)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache$$anonfun$getOrUpdate$2.apply(Cache.scala:20)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.Cache.getOrUpdate(Cache.scala:19)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.CachingFactory.createCompiler(CachingFactory.scala:23)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:62)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)
Warning:scalac: /tmp/sbt_20e2573f/compiler-interface-sources/CompilerInterface.scala:161: error: object creation impossible, since method registerTopLevelSym in trait GlobalCompat of type (sym: this.Symbol)Unit is not defined
Warning:scalac:             new Compiler() with RangePositions // unnecessary in 2.11
Warning:scalac:                             ^
Warning:scalac: /tmp/sbt_20e2573f/compiler-interface-sources/CompilerInterface.scala:165: error: class Compiler needs to be abstract, since method registerTopLevelSym in trait GlobalCompat of type (sym: Compiler.this.Symbol)Unit is not defined
Warning:scalac:     class Compiler extends CallbackGlobal(command.settings, dreporter, output)
Warning:scalac:               ^
Warning:scalac: two errors found
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you "run" this Scala "program"?  IntelliJ might not be configured correctly, but even if it were, the code you've posted isn't independently runnable.

Comment: @RexKerr I can't get this to work. Could you point out a link to code which is actually runnable?

Comment: Looks like IntelliJ IDEA isn't configured correctly.  You're not using the version of Scala it expects, as far as I can tell.  If you're _actually_ using Scala 2.8, I'm not sure modern IntelliJ IDEA supports that.  Why are you using such an old version of Scala?  2.8 is five years old now, and it's been four years since it was the current version.

Comment: @RexKerr I'm using Scala primarily for Natural Language processing libraries http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tmt/tmt-0.4/ which unfortunately support only Scala 2.8. do you have any IDE suggestions in mind which can run on 2.8?

Comment: It's not that important to have an IDE with Scala.  Just use the REPL to try stuff out, and a text editor to edit code (Sublime Text, or example).  Use a modern version of Scala with a modern IDE to help you learn the language.  Or switch to ScalaNLP (http://www.scalanlp.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Your errors are not in the code but in the way you're trying to run the code.

I loaded the code into the REPL and got no error. I loaded the code into IntelliJ and got lots of style warnings but no errors.  I compiled the code and ran it from the command line:

```
%> java HelloWorld
Error: Main method not found in class HelloWorld, please define the
main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

Which is what one should expect.

Comment: I get this error in intelliJ :-/  Edited the question, any idea what might be wrong? or how i should "change" the way i run the code?

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting how you are trying to run your program. Since I am not getting any errors. Let me share you a simple way to run your code snippet.

```
    class HelloWorld{
       var myField = 0;
       def getMyField() : Int = {
        return this.myField;
      }    
    }

    object Test extends App{
      println(new HelloWorld().getMyField())
    }
```

Try to run `Test` object by right clicking inside Test. Hope I was helpful.

Comment: I ran exactly your code, I have scala 2.8.0 installed and intelliJ plugin (this is an old version) I get this error http://pastebin.com/z4k27jHW

Comment: @wolfgang... I changed my scala version to 2.8.0, still I am not getting any issues. May be because of intellij Version and I am using 14.1.1. Kindly update either Intellij Version or Scala Version. Check this for more info   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024905/intellij-12-and-internal-compilation-error-when-building-scala-project

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running IntelliJ, try to build the project (CTRL+F9) and then run it. I had the same issue and it worked for me.